# Final gravity too high

Tags: fermentation, yeast, original-gravity, final-gravity, refractometer

I have an IPA that I've brewed in five gallon batches before. OG at 1.065 and FG at 1.010. Those were hydrometer readings.

I scaled it down for a one gallon batch, and pitched half a packet of yeast (Safale US-05) instead of a full packet. My OG was 1.060 using a refractometer, but my FG is reading 1.041 after 2.5 weeks of fermentation.

Is something throwing the refractometer off? I haven't had this issue before.

Maybe I under-pitched? But half a packet of yeast for a one gallon should be plenty, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your fermentation completed?  At least 3 days in a row with stable gravity?  Is the fermentation temperature the same?

Comment: I didn't check that :/ Same fermentation temp throughout the 2.5 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're measuring FG with a refrac, you need to compensate for alcohol. Alcohol in solution will increase the apparent gravity in a refrac. For this exact reason, I never measure gravity with a refrac after I've pitched yeast.

Comment: This is a good tool for it (part II): https://www.brewersfriend.com/refractometer-calculator/